# get value of second data which has the same name as first data with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

so I have this json

```json
items: [
  {
    id: 123
  },
  {
    id: 456
  }
]
```

and I am trying to get the value with javascript of the second id which has a value of 456, but I have no idea how to because it doesnt have a specified parent by which I could get it.

Comment: This question isn't suppper clear.  Would it work for your circumstance to pull the id by its index?  I.E. if the JSON array were saved to a variable `foo`, you could access the second id by `foo[1]['id']` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your use case isn't exactly clear so the best answer I have for this is to specify the index:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 123
  },
  {
    id: 456
  }
];

const secondId = data[1]?.id;
```

If you are looking for a specific id you can use the find method:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 123
  },
  {
    id: 456
  }
];

const secondObj = data.find(a => a.id === 456);
```

It should also be noted that if you're hitting an API that's querying a database you can't expect that 456 will always be the second object unless the backend code is explicitly ordering it this way.